# How do you set what about:home is on webView, Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, webkit

I am creating a Cocoa web browser, and I noticed that if the webview loads a nil location, it just loads about:home. Since I have not set it, the page just appears white. Is there a way I can change what about:home looks like. Even if it is a simple .rtf file or something.

I looked around, but don't see any way to do this. Am I suppose to create a NSURL and set it to whatever file?

Thanks. Oh, and if code is ever needed, I would be glad to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Inside your App Delegate
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Assuming WebView is called myWebView
    NSString *currentURL = [myWebView mainFrameURL];

    if(!currentURL) {
        NSString *homeResource = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"home" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"default"];

        NSURL *homeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:homeResource];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:homeURL];

        [myWebView loadRequest:request];
    }
}
```

You'll need to have a pre-made file called **home.html** within a folder called **default** located in the **Resources** section of your project.

I suppose this isn't *exactly* replacing `about:home`, but you can always check for `about:home` and handle that appropriately as well.